# Is it possible that lack of memory will cause a NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, heroku, nosuchmethoderror

Recently I've deployed a Java application to Heroku. The application I've deployed also has a background process that can be turned on. The app tends to take up close to all of the 512MBs allocated by Heroku for a single dyno - without the background process running. Everything seems to work fine without the background process turned on, however when I turn on the background process my application starts using more memory than the 512MB allocated and I'm immediately hit with NoSuchMethodErrors. I've included the stack trace below. It seems odd to me that a NoSuchMethodError is thrown due to lack of memory but it is the only variable I can think of. The program works perfectly fine until I turn on the background process.

What's really strange is that all endpoints will serve JSON with no problem for a short while once I restart the application - but then after a variable amount of time the same endpoints will start throwing NoSuchMethodErrors. How can the application find a method and then 10 minutes later not find it anymore?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924505+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.setDefaultContentType(ServerResponseWriter.java:186)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924507+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:46)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924509+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924510+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924550+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924552+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924554+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924556+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924558+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924559+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924561+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:566)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924562+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924564+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924566+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924567+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924570+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924572+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924569+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924573+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924575+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924576+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924578+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924579+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924581+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924582+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924584+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924586+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924587+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
2015-01-31T01:06:37.924594+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's my mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ crewdriver ---
[INFO] com.getworkers:crewdriver:war:1.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.16:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO] |        \- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-servlet-initializer:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.resteasy:async-http-servlet-3.0:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:provided
[INFO] +- net.spy:spymemcached:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.fckeditor:java-core:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.devlib.schmidt:imageinfo:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.31:compile
[INFO] +- com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:jar:3.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.8.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-agent:jar:3.5.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sendgrid:smtpapi-java:jar:0.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.1.v20140609:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.3.0-v_771:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:resources:jar:3.3.0-v20070604:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.core:expressions:jar:3.3.0-v20070606-0010:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.10.0-v20140318-2214:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.10.0-v20140606-1445:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.6.200-v20130402-1505:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.6.0-v20140424-0053:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.5.400-v20140428-1507:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:jar:3.5.200-v20140224-1527:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.core:contenttype:jar:3.4.200-v20140207-1251:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.equinox:app:jar:1.3.200-v20130910-1609:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:filesystem:jar:1.1.0-v20070606:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse:text:jar:3.3.0-v20070606-0010:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.core:commands:jar:3.3.0-I20070605-0010:compile
[INFO] +- net.integrio:tools:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- xdo:xdocore:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.integrio:integrio-db:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.integrio:integrio-db-ext:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.integrio:integrio-js:jar:1.3.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- net.integrio:integrio-json:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.integrio:integrio-utils:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.integrio:integrio-web-tags:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.integrio:integrio-web:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
```

Comment: and what is inside this background process?.. maybe you have declarations in there.. please post source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that lack of memory will cause a NoSuchMethodError?

A cannot think of a way that would happen, from a technical perspective.  Lack of memory would result in `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions.  And even if something "squashed" them, the potential damage to class loading would lead to exceptions saying that the class could not be loaded ... not this one.

A `NoSuchMethodError` happens when you attempt to load an incompatible version of some class.  Specifically, one class has a call to a method on a second class, and the method no longer exists ... in the version of the class code that the classloader has found.

You should check that the JAR containing `BuiltResponse` that you are using at runtime is the same as the one that you built the code against.

It is also possible that this is an version mismatch between some of the libraries that you are using.

---

> Everything seems to work fine without the background process turned on, however when I turn on the background process my application starts using more memory than the 512MB allocated and I'm immediately hit with NoSuchMethodErrors.

I suspect that the extra memory usage is a red herring.  The problem is something to do with the background processes code and its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've been really pulling my hair out over this one. I agree with everything you said, but I've been having a tough time tracking down the wonky dependancy and was hoping that for some crazy reason the memory might be the issue.

The BuiltResponse extends javax.ws.rs.core.Response which contains the getHeaders() method. I'm currently trying to track down where the wrong Response class is getting pulled in. I'm not sure how the background process is affecting it. As far as I can tell it doesn't cary any references to javax.ws.rs.core.Response. mvn dependency:tree included.

Comment: I had thought I solved it - but alas I have not. What's really strange is that all endpoints will serve JSON with no problem for a short while once I restart the application - but then after a variable amount of time the same endpoints will start throwing NoSuchMethodErrors. How can the application find a method and then 10 minutes later not find it anymore?

Comment: Keep looking.  Scan all of the JARs on your deployment platform looking for every instance of the class, and use `javap` to examine the method signatures.  *"How can the application find a method and then 10 minutes later not find it anymore?"*  I can think of scenarios where multiple classloaders are involved ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I finally tracked it down :).

Comment: What was the issue @cregg? ;)